# Consuming Asynchronous asmx Web Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I need to integrate ABP Web Application with existing SOAP asmx WebService writed.
What can be the best strategy for interfacing with exposed SOAP services?

For example, how can i make **async call** to a webmethod in the context of a controller (or application service) after CRUD operation ?

**Edit**

Currently i used this strategy :

1) on .Core project ---> Right click on Services References > Add Services References > Advanced... > Add Web reference, entered the URL of web service

2) Created inside Core Project an helper class for web service managing (initialization, webmethod call etc etc)

3) Consumed web method inside controller ( .Web Project)

The problem is that VS2015 hasn't generated (or badly generated) asynchronous calls to webmethods so i had to use sync method

Anyway what is the best strategy for integrate SOAP asmx web service into the NLayer Architecture implemented in ABP ?

Comment: i did not understand what is the problem in your situation. you can add your webservice reference to the Service Application project. then call the webservice method with await keyword. it is nothing special. same as all other async methods.

Comment: Hi @AlperEbicoglu I forgot some details, please read edited question ;)